# Meaning of in ""? Membership testing empty string literal

Tags: python

I stumbled upon [this](https://raw.github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet/278c6e08d29958be78c0586d9457d602b9296274/pywallet.py) apparently horrific piece of code:

```py
def determine_db_name():
    if wallet_name in "":
        return "wallet.dat"
    else:
        return wallet_name
```

What is supposed `if xx in "":` to mean? Doesn't it always evaluates to `False`?

Comment: Maybe they meant the equally horrible `if wallet_name is ""` and typoed to something that's accidentally slightly more correct?

Comment: lol @ the close vote?

Comment: @Wooble: Then that mistake was made twice in a row. See the `determine_db_dir` function preceding the example function. I do see `is_msg_to_sign is not -1` and `sec is not ''`.. I'd avoid this package like the plague now.

Comment: (it's also full of global variables, not even conveniently all at the top: they are interleaved with function and class declarations, and there are functions declared within other functions... it's a complete mess, so yes we can assume the `in` was intentional)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- (*joking*) At least they had the forsight to set `never_update = False`, so maybe a future update will fix it.

Comment: Before any of us say anything mean, read  http://harthur.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/771/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It'll return `True` if `wallet_name` is itself empty:

```
>>> foo = ''
>>> foo in ''
True
```

It is *horrific* though. Just use `if not wallet_name:` instead, or use `or` and do away with the `if` statement altogether:

```
def determine_db_name():
    return wallet_name or "wallet.dat"
```

which works because `or` short-circuits, returning `wallet_name` if it is not the empty string, otherwise `"wallet.dat"` is returned.

Comment: That should read: `return wallet_name if wallet_name else "wallet.dat"` Using `or` / `and` as conditional expr. is not very pythonic.

Comment: @Ber: It is in this case. Using the conditional expression is overkill here. If you were to use `testexpression and truevalue or falsevalue` then a conditional expression would be the better choice (avoiding problems with a false-y `truevalue`, but for a simple `potentiallyempty or fallbackvalue` *the above perfectly fine* and best of all, *more readable* than the more verbose conditional expression

Comment: `wallet_name or "wallet.dat"` is great.

Answer (score 7):

That expression is true if `wallet_name` is the empty string.

It would probably be clearer if the code had been written as follows:

```
if wallet_name == '':
```

Or just:

```
if not wallet_name:
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `in` is used when checking if a key exists in an array or an element exists in a list.

```
>>> 2 in [1,2,3]
True
>>> 6 in [1,2,3]
False
>>> 'foo' in {'bar', 'foo', 'baz'}
True
```

But it works for strings as well:

```
>>> 'foo' in 'barfoobar'
True
>>> 'foo' in 'barbarbar'
False
```